# Logback/SLF4J File Appender writes log entry multiple times

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I'm having a helper class for logging, that creates a loggier with slf4j and writes the log file.

I'm using a FileAppender to write the log into a defined file.

The problem is, that this FileAppender writes every log line multiple times into the defined file, but just one time in the server.log of the glassfish server.

This is how my class looks like:

```
package de.mycompany.framework.jframework.logging;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * Logger
 * @author Marc Vollmer
 */
public class Logger {
  /**
   * Log Level
   * Default: OFF
   */
  private Level level = Level.OFF;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  public Logger() {
    String sLogLevel = "OFF";
    try {
      sLogLevel = (String)new InitialContext().lookup("jfw/LogLevel");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {

    }
    switch(sLogLevel.toUpperCase()) {
      case "DEBUG":
        level = Level.DEBUG;
        break;
      case "INFO":
        level = Level.INFO;
        break;
      case "TRACE":
        level = Level.TRACE;
        break;
      case "WARN":
        level = Level.WARN;
        break;
      case "ERROR":
        level = Level.ERROR;
        break;
      case "ALL":
        level = Level.ALL;
        break;
      default:
        level = Level.OFF;
        break;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Set the Log Level
   * 
   * @param level Log Level
   */
  public void setLevel(Level level) {
    this.level = level;
  }

  /**
   * Get the Log Level
   * 
   * @return Log Level
   */
  public Level getLevel() {
    return level;
  }

  /**
   * Get Classname from Package Path
   * 
   * @param sPackage Package Path
   * @return Class name
   */
  private String getClassFromPackage(String sPackage) {
    if (sPackage.contains(".")) {
      return sPackage.split("\\.")[(sPackage.split("\\.").length-1)];
    } else {
      return sPackage;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Is the class ignored?
   * 
   * @param sPackString Package PAth
   * @return true if ignored, false if not
   */
  private boolean isIgnoredClass(String sPackString) {
    switch (getClassFromPackage(sPackString)) {
      case "Logger":
      case "Thread":
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Get the Logger
   * 
   * @return SLF4J Logger
   */
  private org.slf4j.Logger getLogger() {
    String sName;
    StackTraceElement[] stacktrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    int i = 0;
    StackTraceElement e = stacktrace[i]; // TODO: Adjust after tests
    while (isIgnoredClass(e.getClassName())) {
      e = stacktrace[++i];
    }
    sName = getClassFromPackage(e.getClassName()) + "." + e.getMethodName();
    LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger = lc.getLogger(sName);
    logger.addAppender(getFileAppender(lc));
    logger.setLevel(level);
    return logger;
  }

  /**
   * Create a file appender
   * 
   * @param lc Logger Context
   * @return File Appender
   */
  private FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> getFileAppender(LoggerContext lc) {
    FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fa = new FileAppender<>();
    fa.setContext(lc);
    fa.setName("FILE");
    try {
      fa.setFile((String)new InitialContext().lookup("jfw/LogFile"));
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
      fa.setFile("../logs/jfw.log");
    }
    PatternLayoutEncoder pl = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    pl.setContext(lc);
    try {
      pl.setPattern((String)new InitialContext().lookup("jfw/LogPattern"));
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
      pl.setPattern("%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5(%level)] [%-50.50(%C{0}.%M)] %m%n%xEx");
    }
    pl.start();
    fa.setEncoder(pl);
    fa.start();
    return fa;
  }

  /**
   * Trace Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   */
  public void trace(String sMsg) {
    if (getLogger().isTraceEnabled()) {
      getLogger().trace(sMsg);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Trace Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   * @param throwable Throwable
   */
  public void trace(String sMsg, Throwable throwable) {
    if (getLogger().isTraceEnabled()) {
      getLogger().trace(sMsg, throwable);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Debug Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   */
  public void debug(String sMsg) {
    if (getLogger().isDebugEnabled()) {
      getLogger().debug(sMsg);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Debug Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   * @param throwable Throwable
   */
  public void debug(String sMsg, Throwable throwable) {
    if (getLogger().isDebugEnabled()) {
      getLogger().debug(sMsg, throwable);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Info Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   */
  public void info(String sMsg) {
    if (getLogger().isInfoEnabled()) {
      getLogger().info(sMsg);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Info Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   * @param throwable Throwable
   */
  public void info(String sMsg, Throwable throwable) {
    if (getLogger().isInfoEnabled()) {
      getLogger().info(sMsg, throwable);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Warn Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   */
  public void warn(String sMsg) {
    if (getLogger().isWarnEnabled()) {
      getLogger().warn(sMsg);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Warn Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   * @param throwable Throwable
   */
  public void warn(String sMsg, Throwable throwable) {
    if (getLogger().isWarnEnabled()) {
      getLogger().warn(sMsg, throwable);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Error Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   */
  public void error(String sMsg) {
    if (getLogger().isErrorEnabled()) {
      getLogger().error(sMsg);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Error Message
   * 
   * @param sMsg Log Message
   * @param throwable Throwable
   */
  public void error(String sMsg, Throwable throwable) {
    if (getLogger().isErrorEnabled()) {
      getLogger().error(sMsg, throwable);
    }
  }
}
```

I did some debug output to the console with System.out.println and e.g. .trace is only called once, writes one log entry in server.log but multiple ones in the given log file.

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Why do you have your own logging helper class? If you are already using SLF4J, you should call it directly. You are hiding the most usefull feature of SLF4J: template messages with arbitraty arguments (like LOGGER.debug("function({}, {})", arg1, arg2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will write de logline twice to the file, because in de LogBack configuration the file is configured and you add it again to the specific Logger. And since log frameworks are dumb in which file to write to, it will write your log statement twice.

Looking at the code, I see you create a FileAppender 2 times for each logstatement. A bit of a waste of memory. And if something happens with the program which cause it to spam your log files, you might run out of file-descriptors on linux environments. If I were you, I should ditch this class and start using SLF4J directly from your classes.

Comment: Thanks. Would be really better to use SLF4J directly.
Did the class only to have the Logger creation seperated from the rest of the framework, but found a better way now.

Comment: Good. Did you try my answer b.t.w.? (removing the appender)

Comment: I made it completely new. In my Framework I'm having a getLogger() Method that previously created an object of my Logger class (if not done somewhen before) and returns it. Now I'm creating the Logback Logger directly inside getLogger() (if not already created. saving the logger in a static attribute).
Now I can even use the Caller Class and Caller Method patterns. The only problem I have is: The first time getLogger() is called is in an EJB (logger gets created, log message written). The second time in a WAR (logger gets reused but no log message written)

Comment: It is still better to user your custom class. For the EJB's and the WAR's, different classloaders are used, so they might use different configurations and we don't want to know how these are handled by the logging framework.
Caching them is also not needed. At a `private static final Logger LOG = ....` at your own class is sufficient to have only one instance per classloader

Comment: Thanks. That works as expected. Now I'm getting all Log entries :)